# How to remove div background colour with JavaScript if class found

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove a parent div background color(.adsense-placeholder) if a advert class (adsbygoogle) detected in it?

```css
.adsense-placeholder { padding: 20px 0 5px 0; margin: 0 0 60px 0; background: #f7f6f1;}
```

```html
<div class="adsense-placeholder">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:380px;height:300px;"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-1094437899690041"
         data-ad-slot="6337850526"
         data-adtest='on'>
    </ins>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this
    $('.adsbygoogle').parent().css("background",'none')

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var gads = $(".adsbygoogle");
   if(gads)
   {
     $( gads ).parent().removeClass("adsense-placeholder");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adsense-placeholder">
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:380px;height:300px;"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-1094437899690041"
         data-ad-slot="6337850526"
         data-adtest='on'>
    </ins>
    asdfasf
</div>
```

Updated your code to check if the adsbygoogle is present then it will remove the parent css class.

Comment: `gads` will always evaluate to `true`. You need to check `gads.length`. And no need to wrap gads in $() again to access it's parent, it's already a jQuery object.